# Unable to access contents of file-scope variable from another function

Tags: c++, recursion

I have 2 functions and one of them is recursive. Here is the real code:

```
class Graph {
public:
    Graph(int v);
    virtual ~Graph();

    void addEdge(int v, int w);

    /**
     * main function that finds and checks SCC
     */
    bool checkSCC();

    /**
     * function that returns reverse (or transpose) of this graph
     */
    Graph getTranspose();
private:
    int V;
    std::list<int> *adj;
    std::vector<int> scc;

    /**
     * fills stack with vertices (in increasing order of finishing times).
     * the top element of stack has the maximum finishing time.
     */
    void fillOrder(int v, bool visited[], std::stack<int> &stack);

    /**
     * a recursive function to print DFS starting from v
     */
    void DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]);
};

Graph::Graph(int v) {
    this->V = v;
    adj = new std::list<int>[v];
}

Graph::~Graph() {
}

void Graph::addEdge(int v, int w) {
    adj[v].push_back(w);
}

bool Graph::checkSCC() {
    std::stack<int> stack;

    bool *visited = new bool[V];
    for(int i=0; i<V; i++)
        visited[i]=false;

    for(int i=0; i<V; i++)
        if(visited[i]==false)
            fillOrder(i, visited, stack);

    Graph gr = getTranspose();

    for(int i=0; i<V; i++)
        visited[i]=false;

    while(stack.empty() == false){
        int v = stack.top();
        stack.pop();

        if(visited[v]==false){

            if(scc.size() > 1) { /*NOTE the problem is HERE !*/
                return true;
            }

            gr.DFSUtil(v, visited);
        }
    }

    return false;
}

Graph Graph::getTranspose() {
    Graph g(V);
    for(int v=0;v<V;v++){
        std::list<int>::iterator i;
        for(i=adj[v].begin();i!=adj[v].end();++i)
            g.adj[*i].push_back(v);
    }
    return g;
}

void Graph::fillOrder(int v, bool visited[], std::stack<int>& stack) {
    visited[v] = true;

    std::list<int>::iterator i;
    for(i = adj[v].begin(); i!= adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if(!visited[*i])
            fillOrder(*i, visited, stack);

    stack.push(v);
}

void Graph::DFSUtil(int v, bool visited[]) {
    visited[v] = true;
    scc.push_back(v); /*NOTE scc only works in this function !! */
    std::cout << v << " ";

    std::list<int>::iterator i;
    for(i = adj[v].begin(); i != adj[v].end(); ++i)
        if(!visited[*i])
            Graph::DFSUtil(*i, visited);
}
```

In this code, if i call Graph::checkSCC, scc preserve it's contents in scope of Graph::DFSUtil but NOT in Graph::checkSCC !! Why this happens ?

I appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

Comment: Then why aren't you showing your actual code? Apparently it's different from this one, or else it would work just the same

Comment: The code is basically the same.. The difference is too small to tell ...

Comment: It's apparently still relevant, otherwise it would work exactly the same way. Also in general it's pointless to provide a working code and asking why a different one (that's not shown) isn't working

Comment: So basically are we supposed to guess what's wrong with the code we haven't seen by looking at the code that works perfectly?

Comment: Dear @UnholySheep, the whole code is fairly complex ... I just thinking, there should be a way to prevent this problem .. Should i replace this snippet with actual code ??

Comment: Ok guys. i replace the code with actual one...

Comment: @HamidMousaviNasab Yes please. You need to provide a minimal example that can be used to reporoduce the issue. A minimal example that doesn't reproduce the issue is useless.

Comment: Sorry my friends! hope this real code, makes clear the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `checkSCC` on one object, and `DFSUtil` on another one (`gr`, which you create in `checkSCC`).

The `scc` member of one has no connection to the `scc` member of the other.

Comment: Dear @molbdnilo, thanks for your reply. If i want to preserve the contents of scc between functions of Graph class, how should i do this ?

Comment: The most obvious way is to pass `DFSUtil` a reference to it.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand, can you show me a link, or some sample ?? Similar to your solution ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is a good starting point.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you @molbdnilo,  NoelWidmer, and 2 other  fellows who decreased points of this question :)